# Symmetric positive definite matrices equivalences

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. Can we conclude that $A$ is invertible and so we can row reduced to the identity?

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then there exists a coordinate matrix $X$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with no zero entries such that $A = X^{-1} \Lambda X$. What can you say about the right hand side?

Comment: @DavidKraemer what you mean cordinate matrix .

Comment: I just mean that it's invertible (in particular, it's the coordinate matrix into the eigenbasis of $A$).

Comment: Whats a cordinate matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An $n \times n$ matrix is invertible if and only if its null space is trivial. Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and assume $A$ is not invertible. Then there exists $y \neq 0$ such that $Ay=0$. That is $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. All the eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix are strictly positive, so $A$ cannot be symmetric positive defnite.

It follows that if $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then $A$ is invertible.

A different approach is, if $A$ is symmetric then $A$ is diagonalizable by an orthongal matrix $U$. Therefore, we have $A=U^* \Lambda U$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and its entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $U^* U=I$. Since $A$ is positive definite, the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are all positive, so it is straightforward to check that $\Lambda$ is invertible. Set $B=U^* \Lambda^{-1} U$. Then
$$
A B=U^* \Lambda U U^* \Lambda^{-1} U=U^* \Lambda \Lambda^{-1} U=I
$$
That is, $B$ is the inverse of $A$.